# Why is this an invalid JSON string for Google Charts

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am attemptint to create a Google Chart (Table chart) with the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            width: 700
        };

        $.getJSON('/LifeListComparison/GetComparison', null, function (jsonData) {
        }).success(function (jsonData) {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
            chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('GoogleTable'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        });
    }

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
        'packages': ['table'],
        'callback': drawChart
    });

</script>
```

The JS code is working fine and the success function is getting called. However, Google Charts is telling me the JSON being returned from the C# service method is invalid. The JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "cols": [
        {"type": "string" ,"label": "Common Name" }, 
        {"type": "string" ,"label": "Scientific Name" }, 
        {"type": "number" ,"label": "Sort Order" }, 
        {"type": "number" ,"label": "Period 1" }, 
        {"type": "number" ,"label": "Period 2" }, 
        {"type": "number" ,"label": "Period 3" }, 
        {"type": "number" ,"label": "Period 4" }, 
        {"type": "number" ,"label": "Period 5" }
        ], 
    "rows" : [
        {"c" : [{"v": "American Coot"}, {"v": "Fulica americana"}, {"v": 3615}, {"v": True}, {"v": True}, {"v": False}, {"v": False}, {"v": False}]}, 
        {"c" : [{"v": "American Crow"}, {"v": "Corvus brachyrhynchos"}, {"v": 19073}, {"v": True}, {"v": False}, {"v": False}, {"v": False}, {"v": False}]}
        ]
}
```

The JSON looks perfectly valid to me, so I must be overlooking something.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ has lots of errors for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a JSON validator tool such as http://jsonlint.com/ ... it's must faster than trying to spot the error.

Booleans should be lowercased.

```
Parse error on line 49:
...               "v": True               
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Comment: Excellent. Simply excellent. That was the problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive, your values for "v" need to be lowercase `true` and `false` vs. what you have now `True` and `False`. Are you manually serializing your JSON in C#? [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) is your friend.

Comment: Oh wow good catch, I didn't see it since the JSON scrolled off the right and clipped.

Comment: @Sukima This isn't a "good catch", this is the most fundamentally basic exercise in debugging. Anybody's first step here should have been to dump this into JSONLint.com, which screams at you with a huge red error message that `"v": True` is a parse error.

Comment: I'm happy to take my compliment back if you don't want it. My wife is always looking for more.